# How do I get an element by its location on the page?

Tags: java, selenium

The problem: I want to extract phone numbers from a page. Every number is hidden under a button called "show contact info". The numbers are not found in the dom until you click the button. When you click the button, the button is replaced by a phone number.

Is there a reliable way to find an element by location on page ? If yes, then I can get the location of the button, click it and then get the phone number at the location of the button.

**Here is the page**: https://sfbay.craigslist.org/pen/apa/5753779484.html
This page will be removed after some time. I can provide a similar page when that happens.

Thanks.

---

I also tried this using only xpath and it failed:

1 - Get the 1st preceding sibling element of "show contact info" buttons.

2 - Using the elements from 1, click the buttons. Buttons are replaced by phone numbers.

3 - Again, using elements from 1, get text the phone numbers.

---

**Code:**

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Temp {

    private static WebDriver browser = new ChromeDriver();

    public static List<String> get_phone_numbers() {
        String url = "https://sfbay.craigslist.org/pen/apa/5753779484.html";
        browser.get(url);

        List<String> phones = new ArrayList<String>();
        String text;
        String phone;
        WebElement contact;

        String before_contact_buttons_xpath = "//*[@id='postingbody']/a[contains(., 'show contact info')]/" +
                "preceding-sibling::*[1]";

        //Get all the preceding sibling elements of "show contact info button."
        List<WebElement> pre_contacts = browser.findElements(By.xpath(before_contact_buttons_xpath));

        for (WebElement pre_contact : pre_contacts) {
            //Click the "show contact info" button. It disappears after click & is replaced by an phone number.
            WebElement temp_contact_btn = pre_contact.findElement(By.xpath("following-sibling::*[1]"));
            System.out.println(temp_contact_btn.getText());
            temp_contact_btn.click();

            //Now get the number from the replaced "show contact info" button.
            contact = pre_contact.findElement(By.xpath("following-sibling::*[1]"));

            text = contact.getText();
            System.out.println(text);

            phone = "000-111-2222";//extract_phone_number(text);

            phones.add(phone);
        }
        return phones;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> phones = get_phone_numbers();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
show contact info
show contact info
```

Comment: Can you show your code that "failed," as well as any errors or how it "failed"?

Comment: @qxz - added the code. thanks.

Comment: Does my answer solve your problem?

Comment: @qxz - your approach works. but, I was wondering if there is a way in which i don't have to open the link in a separate page.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Selenium, but I think that doing a manual request of the URL is the best way to go. When you click the button, the page executes a bunch of JS which initiates and asynchronous request to that URL, and once the request is done, replaces the content. You'd have to detect when that request has finished, and then parse the page... I don't even know if Selenium will handle JS

Comment: It would be way simpler, and have the exact same effect, if you just do the request yourself. Either way, you'd have to parse the returned text to find the phone number, because it doesn't get put into it's own separate element in the DOM.

Comment: Scraping their page/info is against the TOS. https://www.craigslist.org/about/terms.of.use.en.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On that page, clicking the button (actually an `<a>`) triggers an `XMLHttpRequest` that reloads the entire content of the description section. It seems to just do a GET request of the `<a>`'s `href`: https://sfbay.craigslist.org/fb/sfo/apa/5753779484. Try going to that link or right-clicking the "button" and opening the link in a new tab.

Once you have the `<a>` element, I'd suggest requesting the page at its `href` and then somehow parsing the content to get the phone number. This wouldn't be too hard with regular expressions, assuming there aren't any other phone numbers.